# when i open a json encoded array in jQuery it adds &quot;

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array that i want to JSON.encode and then send to jQuery, so that i can do something with the data inside the array in jQuery.

on the server side i do this

> $stepsArray = json_encode($stepsArray);

But when i try to open the encoded array in my script it suddenly changes all the " with & quot;
(im working on a .twig page)

> var stepsArray = '{{stepsArray}}';

I have tried te str.replace the & quot; with " but it doesnt work. I have also tried to use JSON.parse but it also doesnt de anything. Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: I think somewhere along the line a htmlentities() is performed over the resulting page... I am not familiar enough with twig to know where and how exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use this option:

> `json_encode($stepsArray, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

What you can also try is for replacing the string in the javascript is

> `string.replace(/$quot;/g, '\"');`

Can I ask what you mean by "opening it" in your script. What exactly do you want to do with it? jQuery might convert it to HTML friendly text in certain cases, because jQuery's main purpose is to put stuff into the DOM.